# Unable to update SSL cert while using multiple basic listener using WAFV2 Azure App Gateway

Tags: azure, ssl, certificate, azure-keyvault, azure-application-gateway

I am having trouble uploading a new SSL pfx certificate onto my WAF V2 application gateway. I currently have 3 basic wildcard listeners setup (*.contoso.com *.fabrikam.com and *.adatum.com for example) and I would like to update the certificate associated with *.contoso.com.

The problem with using the UI is that if I attempt to update and save the certificate on the listener I get an error message indicating "This Basic HTTP listener cannot use the same frontend port as an existing listener". I understand this is likely because using multiple basic listeners is still in preview and can only be setup via powershell or ARM templates. I originally setup the gateway via ARM templates.

[image]

I instead attempted to update the listener's certificate using powershell. I first uploaded the pfx cert to a key vault. I then created a user managed identity with azure role assignments for both the app gateway and the key vault. After, I ran the following powershell commands from inside the portal's CLI but got the resulting error message.

```
PS > Select-AzureRmSubscription -Scope CurrentUser -SubscriptionName "Pay-As-You-Go"
PS > $appgw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -Name "myappgateway"
PS > $secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "mykeyvault" -Name "contoso-cert"
PS > $secretId = $secret.Id
PS > set-AzApplicationGatewaySSLCertificate -Name "contoso-cert" -ApplicationGateway $appgw -KeyVaultSecretId $secretId
PS > Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $appgw
Set-AzApplicationGateway: Application Gateway 'myappgateway' requires a 'UserAssigned' Identity with 'get' access policy to the referenced KeyVault. Please provide so by using top level 'Identity' property.
```

[image]

[image]

Why am I unable to update the certificate on the basic listener using powershell? Is there any alternative option I can try in order to set the certificate? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure I came across this same issue when looking at the Wildcard Listeners Preview in App Gateway.

I don't have a test environment configured in such a way that I can try this for you at the moment, but I believe the solution was to create a Multisite HTTPS listener (instead of basic) with an arbitrary FQDN, and using the same SSL cert as the one you want to update. Then use that listener to update the SSL cert (you could probably even update the cert at the same time as you create the listener).

Let us know how you get on!

Comment: Oh wow, that worked perfectly. Very hacky but worked like a charm. Thanks so much!